# The disk drive for‭ ‬/media/My_Passport is not ready yet or not present

Tags: boot, mount

I have a dual boot with Mint MATE and Xubuntu on ONE hard drive.‭  ‬I NOW have a problem when booting into Xubuntu with a notice of the following:

The disk drive for‭ ‬/media/My_Passport is not ready yet or not present.‭ ‬Continue to wait,‭ ‬or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.  I would like to eliminate the warning completely!

I recently had connected my USB hard drive but also installed the NTFS configuration tool.‭  ‬Not sure if the new app caused the problem.‭  ‬I also brought the USB hard drive to a friends home who copied some files to his MAC computer.‭  ‬Any HELP would be much appreciated!

```
GNU nano 2.2.6              File: /etc/fstab                                  

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=e15dec6a-4ed3-4267-a88b-aef98e4ce8f0       /       ext4    errors=remount-$
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=4E1AEA7B1AEA6007   /media/My_Passport      ntfs    defaults,nls=utf8,umask$
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=faf77a5c-fff8-49fd-9b83-e73451432379       none    swap    sw      0      $
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add nobootwait to your /etc/fstab. So that it looks like the following:

```
UUID=4E1AEA7B1AEA6007 /media/My_Passport ntfs defaults,nobootwait,nls=utf8,umask$
```

Below is from the fstab man page:

The  mountall(8) program that mounts filesystem during boot also recognises additional options that the ordinary  mount(8) tool does not. These are:  bootwait which can be applied to remote filesystems mounted outside of /usr or /var, without which mountall(8) would not hold up the boot for these; nobootwait which can be applied to non-remote filesystems to explicitly instruct mountall(8) not to hold up the boot for them;

Comment: Dylan, thanks for your help!  I saved your answer for future reference.  I got frustrated and re-installed a similar OS. Thanks again! T

Comment: Did the reinstall fix your problem?